# Class in function javascript in onclick

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have this code:

```
<a class="<?php echo $class; ?>" onclick="del();" >Test</a>
```

Here the function:

```
function del(class){
    alert(class);
}
```

I need to pass the class of element 'a' to function del

How i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `this`

```
onclick="del(this.className);"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
<script>
    function del(a){
    alert(a.className);
}
</script>
<a href="#" class="<?php echo $class; ?>" onclick="del(this);" >Test</a>
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dA6hK/)